# How to calculate the distance between two points in C

Tags: c

I'm stuck on a problem where I'm suppose to create a function to calculate the distance between two points. This is the code we were given in class:

```
typedef struct Point3D {
double x;
double y;
double z;
} point3d_t;

 // Structure for a triangle in 3d
 typedef struct Triangle3D {
point3d_t pts[3];   // Lines between points implicit
 } triangle3d_t;

 // Distance between two points
 double distance(point3d_t *p1, point3d_t *p2){
 
 }
```

Initially I thought that the code in double distance was going to be the following, but I couldn't compile:

```
distance = (sqrt((p2-p1)*(p2-p1)));
```

Anyone what should be in double distance?

Comment: you always need to balance parenthesis

Comment: @GarrGodfrey what do you mean?

Comment: `(sqrt((p2-p1)*(p2-p1))` has 4  `(` but only 3 `)`

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Aha, yeah I fixed it now. It still doesn't compile the code tho

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are *pointers*. While subtracting pointers can sometimes be valid, this is not one of those cases. They both *point to* something that has `x` `y` and `z` coordinates. You are supposed to extract these coordinates, manipulate them,  and use them to calculate the distance.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. aha okey! Should i use p1[x] then to point at the coordinates ?

Comment: Did they actually teach you to work with pointers before giving you this assignment?

Comment: @Cheatah I have issues with concentration so I have a hard time understanding lectures, so I try to do the assignments we get instead and search online for solutions

Comment: Well this is a very inefficient way to learn. If you cannot keep up with lectures, use a book at your own pace.

Answer (score 2):

Getting a distance in 3D space is not much different than in 2D space:

you have 3 vectors, dx, dy, dz. The distance is sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2)

Your code didn't compile because it doesn't balance parenthesis, but it is also incorrect as it only accounts for 2 dimensions and multiplies instead of adds.

For you code, you need to do a simple calculation to get dx, dy, dz:

```
double distance(point3d_t *p1, point3d_t *p2){

    double dx,dy,dz;
    dx = p2->x - p1->x;
    dy = p2->y - p1->y;
    dz = p2->z - p1->z;

    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);
}
```

Note, sign doesn't matter on our deltas, since they get squared and will always be positive.

For a quick proof of the distance formula, you start with Pythagorean theorem, and then realize that any two vectors (say, dx and dy) form a right triangle, with sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) as the length of hypotenuse. The hypotenuse forms another right triangle with dz, so applying pythagorean theorem again, we get:

sqrt(sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2) ^ 2  + dz^2)

which simplifies to:

sqrt( dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 )

Comment: Thanks man! Just another question then, to access the x1 and x2 should it be as p2[x+1] and p1[x] to access these coordinates?

Comment: In C, use -> to access members of a struct or class when derefencing a pointer. Use `.` if you have a reference to the struct rather than a pointer.  So, pt->x   or t.x.   Could also use (*pt).x to really annoy people

Comment: And it's not much different in 1D space either: sqrt(dx^2)  :-)

Comment: @meaning-matters These types of problems aren't usually very hard but I've struggled to understand how to use points in these scenarios ._.

Comment: @relaxedbroccoli I understand, been there.  I hope you Understand why the distance is calculated in this way.  Once you understand something it's easy to rethink it later in case you've half forgotten it over time.